# Drag Drop Featured Application based on Eclipse4 (RCP)

Tags: javafx, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-gef, efxclipse

I am new in Eclipse 4(RCP) and I want to create an application in that any custom component can be defined and these components can be dragged and dropped between parts/views. (Like Scene Builder but it must run into e4)

How can it be possible? And which framework can supply my needs? 
I look into JavaFX and GEF a little. But I could't make decision to use what.

Answer (score 1):

The DND (Drag and Drop) in SWT provides several useful abstractions. 
I think you'll need to get familiar with `DragSource`, `DropTarget` and `Transfer` object.

Please take a look at this article:
https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html

Someone already posted a question like this in Eclipse Forums:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/461505/